# Call POST methods even if the previous request is not yet done using Tornado Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

How can I make a POST method to accept multiple requests and run in parallel?

I have this code and when I make two POST requests to `localhost:5050/`, the second request won't start until the first one gave a response.

```
from tornado import ioloop, web

class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print("1")
        print("2")
        print("3")
        print(self.request.body.rstrip())

app = web.Application([
    web.URLSpec('/', MyHandler)
])

app.listen(port=5000)
print("Listening...")
ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I've read `gen.coroutine` but it doesn't work. What is the best way to handle parallel requests? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't even used `gen.coroutine` or any `async/await` syntax in the code. Of course, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is built with assumption that large part of webserver time is spent handling IO. In non-ideal situation you end up with significant amount of compute  required in webservice, it should be removed from tornado IOLoop. Given you have IO heavy app, tornado will provide needed concurrency. Here is an example simulating an IO heavy app.

```
from tornado import ioloop, web
from time import sleep
from random import randint

class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
  async def post(self):
    wait_val = randint(1, 10)
    await ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, sleep, wait_val)
    print(self.request.body.rstrip())

app = web.Application([
web.URLSpec('/', MyHandler)
])

app.listen(port=5000)
print("Listening...")
ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

To test the app you can use Siege

```
siege "http://127.0.0.1:5000/ POST"
```